# Indicating the type of the email

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I have the following automation program, that sends the email to myself with a specific link added:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import easygui
import tkinter as to
from tkinter import filedialog
import pywinauto
import pywinauto.controls
from pywinauto.application import Application

### easygui commands asking user for the inputs
fieldNames_text= ['','']
fieldNames= ['Subject','Link']
INPUT = easygui.multenterbox('Please fill in', 'FIN and PASSWORD', fieldNames, fieldNames_text)
answer = easygui.ynbox('Any attachement?', 'Attachement', ('Yes', 'No'))

### outlook handling
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'name.surname@company.com'
mail.Subject = INPUT[0]
mail.Body = INPUT[1]

### attachment addition
if answer == True:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    mail.Attachments.Add(file_path)
else:
    pass

### mail sending
mail.Send()
```

However, as per the corporate rules, the user should indicate the type of email (Public, General, Secret, etc.).

This should be defined in the outlook Message pane itself:

[image]

Is there a way to indicate email type within `win32` outlook handling?

Comment: Work with `MailItem.Sensitivity property`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How can I integrate it to the code above?

Answer (score 1):

*Use MailItem.Sensitivity property which sets a constant in the [OlSensitivity enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olsensitivity) indicating the sensitivity for the Outlook item*

*Example*

```
mail.Sensitivity = 3
mail.Send()
```

---

```
+----------------+-------+--------------------+
|      Name      | Value |    Description     |
+----------------+-------+--------------------+
| olConfidential |     3 | Confidential       |
| olNormal       |     0 | Normal sensitivity |
| olPersonal     |     1 | Personal           |
| olPrivate      |     2 | Private            |
+----------------+-------+--------------------+
```