# Sending sensitive mail using outlook 365 using python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, smtplib

I am trying to send email using python in outlook 365. The challenge here is it should be confidential, now I tried using the method in the below link (along with code snippet).

Code executes without an error but it does not select any sensitivity property. It just opens as a default mail.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63170482/indicating-the-type-of-the-email

import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'name.surname@company.com'
mail.Subject = 'xyz'
mail.Body = 'abcdefgh'
mail.Sensitivity = 3
mail.Send()
```

Comment: Do you see the item sent and marked as confidential in the `Sent Items` folder?

Comment: It reaches the sent item folder but does not have any level of security marked on the same

Comment: Where do you expect to see the level of security on the item?